# How to get the VSO calendar extension working in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs

I have been trying to find a solution that allows us to display a long term schedule of all our work. TFS doesn't seem to do this out of the box and it looks like the best solution would be VSO's Team Calendar extension. Apparently TFS 2015 supports VSO extensions but if I package the extension up in a zip file, go to /tfs/_admin/_extensions and then upload it then I get the message "Invalid zip archive file." Before I investigate this further I'd just like to check that I'm on the right path and this is something that TFS actually supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have on-premises TFS 2015 **Update 2**, you can download a Team Calendar extension from here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.team-calendar

Just click the "Download" button and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

On-prem TFS doesn't yet support extensions. It's coming in a future update.

You can see the features in VSO versus on-prem TFS on [VisualStudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso)